# Replace Get-ADUser with Ldap Filter to get away from RSAT Module

Tags: powershell, filter, ldap

I want to replace this line `get-aduser -identity $env:username -properties passwordlastset` with an ldap Filter.
I only need the Aduser information for the actual PC user and the date of the last password change.

Comment: [1] how are you going to apply the LDAP filter? ///// [2] what have you tried? how did it fail to do what you need? what errors did you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
$searcher.Filter="(&(samaccountname= $env:username))"
$results=$searcher.findone()
$b = [datetime]::fromfiletime($results.properties.pwdlastset[0])
```

Fixed it by myself, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP filter actually used by `Get-ADUser -Identity $someSAMAccountName` is:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=username-goes-here))
```

Comment: How'd you get this?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala As I've explained before, .NET decompilers are your friends - that being said, the first time I observed this for the AD module was by using Wireshark to dump the on-wire LDAP request. Give it a try :-)

Comment: I forgot lol you and @Mklement0 should write a book